# Second being lost when converting time to string

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3 and PHP 5.6. I believe CakePHP may be playing a role in this problem (IE, casting the SQL DateTime entry to it's own DateTime format.)

I have an SQL table which has a series of entries containing DateTime values. They are entered as so:

```
2016-07-29 17:46:45
```

I am currently not doing any sort of parsing of this time in my controller, I simply pass it on to the view via `$this->set()`

In the view, I can use the CakePHP debugger to see that the date appears as an array which contains a time value, a fixedNowTime value and a timezone value. The time value appears as so:

[image]

I can see that the second is indeed included with the time. But when I try to echo it out, the second is lost no matter how I attempt to do so.

**What I've tried**

Here's examples of what I've attempted and the outputs:

**1.**

```
$dateval = date_parse($adatevalue);
echo $dateval['second'];
```

-No output at all

**2.**

```
$dateval = strtotime($adatevalue);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateval);
```

Output (notice second is lost):

```
2016-07-29 17:46:00
```

**3.**

```
$dateval = date_parse($adatevalue['time']);
echo $dateval['second'];
```

Output:

```
Cannot use object of type Cake\I18n\FrozenTime as array
```

Attempting to do these in the controller yields the same results.

Comment: The debug kit output is a little deceiving, as it will only show the objects debug info (`__debugInfo()`), which is always an array. Your dates aren't arrays, they are actually date/time objects as the error you are showing suggests. That being said, are you saying that even `echo $adatevalue` will output `45` as `00`?

Comment: Thanks for that information @ndm. `echo $adatevalue` will output `7/29/16, 5:46 PM`.

Comment: So you're on `en_US` locale. What about `$adatevalue->i18nFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::FULL)` or `$adatevalue->format('h:i:s')`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was hoping for. Create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug kit output is a little deceiving, as it will only show the objects debug info ([**`__debugInfo()`**](http://php.net/__debugInfo)), which is always an array. Your dates aren't arrays, they are actually date/time objects as the error you are showing suggests.

The seconds being lost is due to your attempts to transform the date/time object. Your configured `en_US` locale uses a date format pattern that doesn't output the seconds (`M/d/yy, h:mm a`), so `strtotime` will receive a datetime string like `7/29/16, 5:46 PM`, causing the seconds to be lost.

If you want to change the default output format, either format the output explicitly, by using for example `i18nFormat()` or `format()`, something like

```
$adatevalue->i18nFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::FULL)
```

```
$adatevalue->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

```
$adatevalue->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

or set/change the default output format in your bootstraps date/time type configuration, like

```
\Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Formatting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Setting the Default Locale and Format String](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)**